# Main UI processing thread messages

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I am writing a win32 application which allows an operator to perform testing on 4 devices at a time. So i have 4 threads running simultaneously, this works as intended (though could be more efficient). The problem i have is when the thread tries to send either a Pass or Fail to the main UI to be displayed to the operator, i have debugged the PostMessage call and this returns '1', but nothing is shown in the listbox that should display the result. Here's some code;

Thread function first, this is the same as the other 3 threads

```
void Thread1(PVOID pvoid)
{
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfTests1;i++) {     
        //DWORD id = GetCurrentThreadId();
        int ret;
        double TimeOut = 60.0;
        int Lng = 1;
        test1[i].testNumber = CMD_TOOL_BUZZER;
        //test1[i].testNumber = getTestNumber(test1[i].testName);
        unsigned char Param[255] = {0};
        unsigned char Port1 = port1;

        ret = PSB30_Open(Port1, 16);
        ret = PSB30_SendOrder (Port1, test1[i].testNumber, &Param[0], &Lng, &TimeOut); 
        ret = PSB30_Close (Port1);
        int result = 0;

        if(*Param == 1) {
            PostMessage(hWnd,WM_TEST_PASS,i,(LPARAM)"PASS");
            test1[i].passed = true;
         }
        else PostMessage(hWnd, WM_TEST_FAIL, i, (LPARAM)"FAIL") ;
     }
    _endthread();
}
```

In main, the message handler;

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
```

And finally user defined message;

```
case WM_TEST_PASS:
    i = wParam;
    SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd,IDT_RESULTLIST1,LB_ADDSTRING,i,(LPARAM)"PASS");
    MessageBox(hWnd,"test",0,0); //debug
break;
```

Is there anything else i require to display the results in the listbox, i am at my wits end with this.

Note, i have tried PostThreadMesage and SendMessage and get the same results, which leads me to think the issue lies with the message handler or my user-defined message

Thanks for looking

Comment: Are you posting to the correct `hWnd`?

Comment: Hi Roger,Yes hWnd is the handle to my main window, everything is contained within this

Comment: Thanks, and have you verified with the debugger that your main window gets to the `SenDlgItemMessage` ok? Also, is the `hWnd` in the `SendDlgItemMessage` the handle of the window that owns the list box?

Comment: Okay i ran the debugger with a break point at the SendDlgItemMessage and it does not get to this code, so it seems the issue is prior to this. hWnd is the handle of the window that owns the list box

Comment: Right so make sure that your custom message id's are defined correctly so that thread and the main window are both using the same values. Maybe post more of your message loop code in case there's an earlier problem.

Comment: Custom Message ID's:   #define WM_TEST_PASS     WM_APP + 0x100
#define WM_TEST_FAIL     WM_APP + 0x101   Regarding message loop, that is basically all there is

Comment: Then either your message loop isn't getting called at all (doubtful) or the custom messages are being ignored/bypassed earlier - maybe a missing `break` in an earlier `case` - just thinking out loud - it would help to see the complete message loop code.

Comment: Roger, by message loop code are you referring to the WndProc, if you are posting this could be an issue as there probably 500 lines of code contained within it

Comment: Ok, then as a temporary measure, make the WM_TEST_PASS message the first `case` in the `switch` statement. If you still don't hit it, it must be that the thread is sending to the wrong `hWnd` - everything else looks fine.

Comment: Okay, i placed WM_TEST_PASS as the first switch statement, still nothing, i'm beginning to seriously hate threads :)

Comment: What is 'TranslateAccelerator'?  Whatever it is, it could intercept your custom message by returning false.

Comment: This was auto-generated by Visual Studio so i have never touched it, to be honest my winapi skills are very rusty, been over 10 years since i last used it, just removed it and still having the same issues

Comment: 'auto-generated by Visual Studio' - OK, there's a good place to start debugging :)  Put an else block in to catch messages that are rejected by 'TranslateAccelerator' and check for your custom message number/s.  Put a Beep() call, or something in and break on it, (or listen:).

Comment: Placed a break at the else in translatemessage, never activated it so no messages are getting rejected (as far as i am aware)

Comment: OK, now I'm stuck too.  The PostMessage() API works else Windows would not work at all, you say the hwnd is correct, it's not the mysterious 'TranslateAccelerator' and the WndProc is surely getting called for all the other messages else your window would be a lot deader than it is:).  The only other possibility I can think of is that RecreateWindow() got called between the time you communicated the HWND to the thread and the time your thread posted the message, so invalidating the original HWND.  OK, yes, straw-grasping time :(

Comment: Is there anyway to ensure/force the message to be processed?

Comment: also when i say hwnd is correct, i'm assuming that since my main window is hwnd, all objects on this window will use hwnd also, i'm clutching at straws also because the other listbox that is created outside the thread is populated using hwnd

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but when i try to evaluate hwnd during debug mode i get this:- unused CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated. Or is this microsoft playing funny buggers again?

Comment: Well, well, well, i decided to re-install Visual Studio as i really couldn't think of anything else to try and i did have an issue a while back were my UI wasn't showing, re-installing fixed it. This time after installing again, compile and run the program works as it should. Thanks to everyone that has chipped in on this, much appreciated. Now of to find a decent development suite :)